# How to navigate back to my app from a browser page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-web-browser

In my flutter app I navigate to a website with URL_Launcher and it opens in the external Browser. After adding an user account on success page I need to navigate back to specific page. Kindly help with examples for the same.

Im using the below code with URL_Launcher

```
launchUrl(Uri.parse(addAccount.scaRedirect), mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                          webViewConfiguration: const WebViewConfiguration());
```

Comment: Did you find something about this?